# ember.js - How to connect two components on different routes?

Tags: ember.js

I have a parent and a child component that need to interact. Normally I would use [contextual components](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/01/15/ember-2-3-released.html#toc_contextual-components)). I this case this does not work, as the two components are not on the same route template. The parent component is on one route and the child component is on the child route and as far as I know, I can't pass the contextual component to the {{outlet}}.

```
Route       | Component
----------------------------
route       | parentComponent
route.sub   | childComponent
```

I currently see two options:

1. Move the parent component logic to the controller
2. Use a service

I would like to avoid both options, as the same parent child components might be displayed twice at the same time. In both cases I don't see an other option as to use some kind of ID to connect the correct child with the correct parent and I don't like that, as I find it hard to debug and read.

```
       Controller/Service
        ∧              |
        |              ∨
      action()      ?  or  ?  -> use of ID
        ∧           |      |
        |           ∨      ∨
child child       parent parent
```

Is there an other way to do that?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is, not possible to implement the solution without using two options you provided.

I believe your mentioned component is not exhibiting proper parent-child relations since parent lives in one root and child lives in another route.

Suppose TemplateA - has `{{comp-a}}` and `{{comp-b}}` - this is called sibling component. here `comp-b` cant communicate to `comp-a`, but it is possible through sending actions to common controllers/routes.

Suppose TemplateA - has `{{comp-a }}` and inside `comp-a` has `{{comp-b}}` - this is called parent-child component, here child component(`comp-b`) can communicate to parent component `comp-a`.

Components will communicate through bubbling action, and action logic should be implemented in source/owner of the data.

In your case, answer is depending on who is the owner of the data,

1.If components are not used in same nested route hierarchy then I prefer to give data ownership to service.
2.If both components are used in same nested route hierarchy then I prefer to give data ownership to controller/route 
ie.,
parent-route -> will load data and pass required data to parent component.
parent-route.sub -> get the child component required data from parent route (you can use `modelFor` `controllerFor` method) and pass on the child component. Now child component can trigger action from here to till application route to communicate.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed feedback.

Comment: I suspected that. In my case the parent and child component don't work with the same data. They need to communicate only in the purpose of how to show and decorate stuff. I guess I then go with the controller/route option. And move as much as possible in Query Parameters.